# Waiting time for editor's decision for an article with status "Reviews Completed" for 4 months?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, editors, communication

The academic journal paper I submitted to a Q1 Springer journal has been in the position of "Review Completed" since February 6, 2023, and is still in that status as of today, June 21, 2023. When should I expect to hear back from the editor?  If it is possible for me to write to the editor, please provide me with a template.

Comment: How to write the letter to editor? Sample letter Plz

Comment: keep it short and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

Many journals provide publication metrics that can give you an idea of the average timeline. It's really not possible to know exactly when you'll hear back though. Your paper may be just sitting on an editors desk with a pile of other work. Or the submission portal was incorrectly updated and it is still being reviewed. Maybe they are looking for an additional reviewer and never changed the status. Who knows.

In any case, just email the editor and ask about the status of the paper. No template needed.